# Incrementing the value of a ROI that (possibly) partially is out of bounds in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that needs to be partially incremented with the values of another (smaller) array. However, even if the smaller array does start inside the bounds of bigger array, **it can overflow in some cases like shown below.**

[image]

In this case I still want the values to be incremented/modified with a manner that **clips the overflowing indices and uses what remains inside the bounds.**

Here is how I do it at the moment

```
h = big_image.shape[0]
w = big_image.shape[1]

small_image = make_small_image(c) # c is the edge length

if (x+c) > w:
   small_image = small_image[:(w - x), :]

if (y+c) > h:
   small_image = small_image[:, :(h - y)]

big_image[y:y + c, x: x + c] += small_image.T
```

I wonder if there is a **easier and faster way** to do it (an API or a better technique etc.)

Comment: Why the downwote? I still dont understand whats wrong with my question. :)

Comment: What's the trouble with my answer? It is correct and the only way to do it easier and faster. Perhaps someone downvoted it, because it is already answered but the answer is not marked as accepted. But imho your question is good, thus I upvoted it.

Comment: Oh no, your answer is just fine and I am strongly considering upvoting it. But the downvote was there, it happened right after I've asked the question.

When it comes to accepting your answer, I am just waiting for two days or three and then I will accept it. Thank you for the understanding.

Comment: Ok great, I am glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are modifying the array `small_image` and thus creating a new copy of the data when the if-condition is `True`. Instead you could just create a memory-view to the cropped small image:

```
small_img_memview = small_image[:(w - x), :(h - y)]
```

This should always be correct, even for the case that the if-conditions are `False` and should be faster than copying.

Of course you can also just write all of your code in one line:

```
big_image[y:y + c, x: x + c] += small_image[:(w - x), :(h - y)].T
```